# How to get an element identified by SeleniumWebdriver given that the customized Xpath highlights the element in the inspect window correctly

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I am using an **Xpath** selector `By.xpath("//button[@name='new-page']")` to identify an object using Selenium Webdriver.

Also I cross verified that this Xpath is correct as it highlights the correct object when I do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and put it in  the inspect window tab.

However, my script fails with the following error: `no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[text()='Home']"}`.

I am using Cucumber with Eclipse as my IDE to automate this scenario. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

The HTML content for the object is:

```
<button name="new-page" type= "button class="btn btn-primary" data-reactid = ".0.1.1.1.0.1.2.$btn-new-page">New Page</button>
```

Comment: I am not sure why the html content is getting reflected as "New Page" in my post.The correct html content is  <button name="new-page" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-reactid=".0.1.1.1.0.1.2.$btn-new-page">New Page</button>

Comment: I guess your issue with other element not with the new page as the exception shows unable to find element with xpath //div[text()='Home'] but your xpath is "//button[@name='new-page']"

Comment: Yes,you are correct.That is because it is trying to look for the Home page instead of the new page.The ideal sequence is that the script should first click on new page and then on home button which appears in another page.I think it is unable to identify the New-Page element somehow.,

Comment: You means to say, it is not clicking on new page button?

Comment: Yes.It is not clicking the New-page button.

Comment: It may be taking long time to load second page.if it is not able to identify new page button then it will throw no such element for that button. But you are getting error for home button.

Comment: share stacktrace. Btw you can use `By.name("name")` locator

Comment: Can you sum up your exact manual steps along with the relevant HTML DOM please? Thanks

Comment: I used By.Name("name") locator and it worked :) Thanks all for your comments.